# Is it true that the SSD of a Macbook Pro (2018) cannot be swapped for another one?

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, data-recovery

Is it true that the SSD of a Macbook Pro 15-inch (A1990 EMC3215) cannot be changed by itself? This is one of the latest models which have a touch bar.

I know for a fact that the SSD of a Macbook Air 11-inch (2013) (A1465 EMC2631) can, as I have done it before. But the shop in my neighbourhood says this is not the case with A1990 EMC3215. I hope to have confirmation that this is correct.

If this is correct:

I am in a situation where I need to recover data from my Macbook Pro 15-inch (A1990 EMC3215)'s SSD, but I still need to continue using the same machine. I was thinking of taking it out and replacing it with a new SSD. This way, I can send the original SSD for recovery (or I can at least delay recovery efforts), while still be able to use my Macbook. If I just continue using the original SSD, there is high risk of the OS overwriting my accidentally deleted files. I'd like to continue using my Macbook A1990 EMC3215 while I explore the possibility of recovering data from the original SSD.

If I can't swap out the SSD for another one, is there anything else I can do if I cannot get a new/another machine?

Comment: Note: there was a similar question. Unlike that one, I do not think this is (1) hypothetical (it's on a real scenario now) (2) too broad (I am only asking 2 very related question on what can be done)

Comment: I’m going to have to down vote this - it’s too broad. You might want to pay someone to help you with data recovery efforts rather than keep asking a string of quite long, not clear questions here. If there are multiple questions in a question it will be voted to be closed as too broad. Let’s clear this up - you mention two models and two questions. Can you fit your question into about three clear sentences, a couple bullet points of facts (hardware year / model) with an edit?

Comment: This is now the latest in a series of ***11 questions*** about essentially the same thing, or a continuation of... none of which would have been needed if you'd had a backup strategy in place beforehand.

Comment: @bmike may i know what's unclear about my question which is as simple as: is it true that I cannot change my Macbook Pro 15-inch (A1990 EMC3215)'s SSD (when I can do that with my Macbook Air 11-inch (2013) (A1465 EMC2631)?

Comment: [...] and if yes, then how can I follow jksoegaard's suggestion which was to “stop using the original drive and send that in - and then continue working on your clone drive instead” (given that I cannot get a new machine)?

Comment: @Tetsujin I know you have said this couple of times, but it's a little like working on spilled milk here. In future I will take note of this, but now this can't really be used on the issue at hand.

Comment: Removed from context, the answer is basically 'no' you can't change the SSD on a soldered board, you replace the board.

Comment: Ok. I’ll release the hold if you don’t get why it’s too broad and / or unclear.

Comment: I would suggest you to simplify your question so as to be a self contained one where it would be easier to get your point and answer you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tear down of the Mac that answers your questions
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IA9VqG4j5kk

As far as accessing data on a dead MacBook there is a proprietary
connection inside that lets the apple store directly access the SSD without powering the laptop on.

Edit:  Reading the rest of your post... If the laptop is even turned on your accidentally deleted files are toast.  SSD TRIM will wipe out the now 'unused' sectors and permanently erase your data.